# Linkedin preview states: "Cannot display preview. You can post as is, or try another link." when entering link to my Wordpress site

Tags: api, linkedin-api

When I enter the link to my WordPress site babid-management.nl or any post page within that site (e.g https://babid-management.nl/blog/new-autopost-test/) I get the message "Cannot display preview. You can post as is, or try another link." popped up.

I checked LinkedIn support pages and can confirm the OpenGraph meta properties are available (see also results from OpenGraphCheck.com at http://opengraphcheck.com/result.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbabid-management.nl%2Fblog%2Fnew-autopost-test%2F#.WfmbiWiPKUk

What else could prevent LinkedIn to pull this post from my website?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your server is blocking the LinkedIn Bot agent:

**Apache (such as in Wordpress)**:

If you have **Better Security Plugin** installed, you need to remove the following line in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Link [NC,OR]
```

**IIS (such as ASP.Net)**

In your `web.config` file if you have a blocking rule based on HTTP_USER_AGENT, remove the following line:

```
<add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Link" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still working on this Bas... But I did find that someone did a pretty extensive step by step relating to oembed code interfering or preventing linkedin.

https://pmig.at/2017/10/26/linkedin-link-preview-for-wordpress/

Suggests installing Disable Embeds plugin to fix the problem.